# How to (re)enable clipboard on WinServer2008 VM (VirtualPC)

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, microsoft-virtual-pc, clipboard

At some point yesterday, the clipboard on my VM stopped working.
The VM is a Windows Server 200 Standard SP2 running in Windows VirtualPC, itself running on Windows7 Enterprise.

I can "copy" and "cut" text -- but nothing pastes (cut is particularly galling, since the target cannot be restored, except by Undo. Which *does* work).

`Ctrl-C`, or `right-click >> copy`, both fail.
`Ctrl-V` or `right-click >> past`e fail -- the latter isn't even available, `paste` is greyed-out.

I can copy and paste text from my host into the VM.
I cannot  copy and paste from the VM into the host.

I've run ProcMon filtered down to `clip.exe` and nothing appears.
(this also appears to be the case in my host machine; apparently clip.exe is not the main clipboard)
However, when I pipe `dir | clip` from the shell, I do get entries. (but the output is not available via paste).
Again, nothing that jumps out at me.

I've rebooted the VM several times, disabled, and re-enabled integration features.

I've checked the event log, but don't see anything significant (mostly about network printers).

Comment: This is NOT the same as VM<=>Host as seen @ http://superuser.com/questions/60783/copy-and-paste-from-virtual-pc-has-stopped-working

Answer (score 0):

I did *another* complete shutdown of the VM **and** a complete shutdown of the Host PC.

After restarting the host and the VM, `paste` was now available.

Unknown what *"resolved"* the situation.

Comment: I'm holding off accepting my own answer for a few days, in the hopes that somebody shows up with something technical. I hate reboot-voodoo.